# Where should I specify a pinentry program for GnuPG 2.0 and later?

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent, git-crypt, git-secret

I'm going to introduce git-crypt or git-secret to encrypt the credentials information described in a git repository.

This needs GnuPG(GPG) to provide a way of encryption. I'v already installed the following program with homebrew:

- gnupg
- gnupg2
- pinentry-mac

As of GnuPG 2.0, no need to install gpg-agent seperately.

[What’s new in GnuPG 2.1](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html)

But how to set up pinentry-program? I tried to set pinentry-mac to pinentry-program in gpg-agent.confg as I did in the former versions. It did't work for me.

What file is the replacement of gpg-agent.conf or are there any extra processes needed like restarting gpg?